# The declaration of ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

At the compilation (gcc Linux) of the following simple program:

```
  1 #include <vector>
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 #include <iterator>
  4 #include <algorithm>
  5 using namespace std;
  6
  7 int main()
  8 {
  9         vector<int> numvec;
 10         istream_iterator<int> is;
 11         istream_iterator<int> eof;
 12         is=istream_iterator<int>(cin);
 13         copy(is, eof, back_inserter(numvec));
 14         cout << "Number of values inserted: " << numvec.size() << endl;
 15
 16         ostream_iterator<int> os;
 17         os=ostream_iterator<int>(cout);
 18         copy(numvec.begin(), numvec.end(), os);
 19
 20 }
```

I got the following error:

```
line 16: error: no matching function for call to 
'std::ostream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char> >::ostream_iterator()'
```

Is it not possible to only declare ostream_iterator, without defining it? This is the case with istream_iterator (lines 10 and 11). Why it does not work for ostream_iterator?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just initialize `is` and `os` instead of retyping everything to assign to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No constructor available for [ostream_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/) with empty argument list.

ostream_iterator requires a `basic_ostream<charT,traits>&`

However [istream_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/) has a constructor with empty argument list which marks end-of-stream.

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iterator>
  #include <algorithm>
  using namespace std;


  int main()
  {
          vector<int> numvec;
          istream_iterator<int> is;
          istream_iterator<int> eof;
          is=istream_iterator<int> (cin);
          copy(is, eof, back_inserter(numvec));
          cout << "Number of values inserted: " << numvec.size() << endl;

          ostream_iterator<int> os(cout);
          os=ostream_iterator<int>(cout); // Not required !

          copy(numvec.begin(), numvec.end(), os);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to

```
16         ostream_iterator<int> os(cout);
18         copy(numvec.begin(), numvec.end(), os);
```

17-th line was deleted.

Comment: That's pretty much the exact same thing with the same issue that exists regardless of the initialization vs. assignment.

Comment: But it makes it is runnable, I have no idea what author wanted to receive.

Comment: I apologize. I hate it when this happens, but I've thought for the past year or more that it needs two arguments.

Comment: No problem @chris, cheer up! :)

Comment: The point is I want to use the same ostream_iterator for two different streams, eg. write to two different files